# How can I get an asset from another file and use it as a favicon?

Tags: html

Basically, I have an `assets` file where I have all the assets of my project. This is outside of my project folder. I want to set an image from the `assets` file as my Favicon. My current file structure looks something like this:

- Project
- Assets

  - image.png
- index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="Project/Assets/image.png" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Add this in your Head tag.

Comment: How can I do this on Github? Should I just use ../assets/image.png

Comment: if your index.html file and project file are on the same level then you should use my code  .this   ../assets/image.png used when your index file are on another level